# No spoiler alert - What am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Here're some of my properties:

```
1. People usually put a hole in front of me, I do not know why.  
2. Some refers me as Delend, but that's not my name.  
3. Inverted, I might have shown myself.  
4. I might be small, but once shifted, I became invisible.
```

What am I?

Hint 1:

> By giving out a hint I'm almost giving out the answer, right here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> .1

Because

> "." is below ">" and "1" is below "!" combining the 2 creates the spoiler block quote.

People usually put a hole in front of me, I do not know why.

> with .1, most people place a 0 before to make 0.1 - As shown in answer by Bass

Some refers me as Delend, but that's not my name.

> Del is on the "." button on the number pad. End is on the "1" on the number pad.

Inverted, I might have shown myself.

> For List point 1., if you would have written ".1", then you would have shown the answer right away.

I might be small, but once shifted, I became invisible.

> using the shift key while pressing ".1" on the keyboard creates the spoiler block quote.

Comment: I will give the check mark here after you figured out the missing part.  You should get that if you figured out the rest!

Comment: Missing part?: rot13(pbhyq "vairegrq" zrna "fjnccrq" v.r. "!>")

Comment: Yup you got it!

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> the numpad decimal point?

1. People usually put a hole in front of me, I do not know why.

You can write a

> zero in front of positive numbers smaller than one, that is, 0.05 and .05 are the same number.

2. Some refers me as Delend, but that's not my name.

> "del" and "end" are words that are found on numpad keys. Maybe there's a layout where they are both on the decimal point?

3. Inverted, I might have shown myself.

> Not sure about this, might have something to do with the [inverted comma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inverted_comma)?

4. I might be small, but once shifted, I became invisible.

> The decimal point is very small pixelwise, but if you press shift, you get the unprintable "del" instead.

Comment: Heh. Great minds... . ;)

Comment: @Bass Very close, very!

Answer (score 6):

Possibly

> the numpad '0' key (alternate 'Ins')

Reasoning 1:

> the key is typically separated from the arrow keys by a gap ("hole") to its immediate left

Reasoning 2:

> the key is located just below 'End' (the alternate for numpad '1') and to the right of 'Del' (the alternate for numpad '.'), i.e. 'Delend'

Reasoning 3:

> This could either refer to the fact that 0 is its own additive inverse (-0 = 0), or to the fact that the 'Ins' key inverts the status of overtype (on-to-off, off-to-on) in most applications, and hence is its own inverse

Reasoning 4:

> the number 0 is small, but when the Shift key is held down (the key becomes 'Ins'), it produces no visible character when pressed

Comment: Close, but not as close as Bass's answer